# Org-mode beamer export: suppressing title slide?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, beamer

How can I suppress the generation of the title slide in org-mode beamer export?  Adding `title:nil` to an `#+options` line does not do the trick.  I find plenty of tips on customizing the title page, but what I want is to make the thing go away.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you post a MWE (actually a MNWE I guess) org file? Also, the version of org-mode you are running?

Comment: @user3788685: that answer is obsolete - the function that it mentions no longer exists in modern versions of org-mode (9.x.x).